# Is it possible to populate Power M Query parameters with the filtered results of another query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a very large dataset in Azure Data Explorer that will grow to millions of rows, the data is time series data for a large number of objects/assets in our database. I need to provide a report in PowerBI where users can select a time frame, and the object ID's they wish to return and the time series data for the objects and time period they want will be returned.

I have 2 queries, one which returns a distinct list of the objects in the time series table, and a second that will return the data for the selected IDs using a parameter to define the ID list.

I'm struggling to see how it is possible to pass the filtered list of IDs from the first query into the second query, either in the same report or a second report. There doesn't seem to be a way to use the sliced ID list as a parameter value for the time series query.

I have configured a report as I think it should work, but the IDList parameter isn't ever updated with the selected IDs from the first query, it is only ever the default value that I set when I create the parameter.

Has anyone done anything similar where they use one query output as a parameter for a second query?

I am passing a dynamic M parameter into the query:
[image]

I have brkoen the ID column of my object query into its own query:

[image]

That query is then assigned to the parameter:

[image]

When I try and apply those changes, I get this error which suggests that because i'm using dierctquery, I can't use the results of other queries to drive it's results?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters)?

Comment: I am using Dynamic M query parameters in both my queries to ADX, but can't seem to get the value of the timeseries data query to update with a value from the results of the first query.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r8N4.png

Comment: I have added some detail to the description to be clearer about what I have tried. Thanks